# Does Kubernetes runAsUser security context setting, override the user setting in the container image?

Tags: kubernetes

After reading about kubernetes pod security context in the k8s documentation (https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/security-context/) - I have a question that I could not find an answer to.

The security context allows adding runAsUser setting with a user ID. Can this be used to run a container image that has NOT been modified to run as a non-root user. Meaning if the runAsUser is set to say 1000 and the container image that runs in this pod, does not use a USER directive / or basically is built to run as root, will the runAsUser setting override the container image?
Will the container run with user 1000 or will it continue to run as root?

Working on to setup Kubernetes and try this scenario in a cluster but would like to understand the concept and what the expected behavior is.

Answer (score 2):

Yes this will run the container with the provided user id (ignoring the user in the container image).

Comment: does that mean that we don't need to make changes to the container image to run it as non-root?

Comment: It depends on the image and application. Some images have problems when started as non-root users/users that are not in /etc/passwd. If that is the case you'll have to adapt the image.

Comment: I'd like to play this back so that I understand it correctly. `runAsUser` and `runAsGroup` sets the user and group ID for all containers running in the pod. And these override the `USER` directive in a Dockerfile. Is that accurate? Meaning the `USER` is not required alongside `runAsUser` and `runAsGroup`

Comment: Yes, runAsUser will overwrite whatever user is defined in the container image.